# Magento: Magmi security

Tags: magento, magmi

I have installed Magmi via FileZilla following the instructions on the Magmi wiki. I followed the instructions for common users because I don't know much about webservers, [link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Installing_Magmi).

When the permissions are set to 705 I can't get on the Magmi page. I get a 403 Forbidden error when I go to website.com/magmi/web/magmi.php. Setting the permissions on 777 works but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

How can I get to the Magmi page with the permissions set on 705?
Any other tips on how to secure the Magmi page are welcome too. I don't understand the Magmi wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The correct file permissions for Magmi and Magento should be

**755** for Folders
**644** for Files

Run this shell command in your Magento root folder to set all files and folders to their correct permissions set:

```
chmod -R 755 *; find -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: ...and the server needs to own the files, apache for example. `chown -R  apache:apache  magmi`